# unix email server with gui interface

Tags: email, unix

I am running unix CentOS 5 and looking for free mail server that has GUI web interface for managing accounts.
It be used with windows based clients on outlook express.

Answer (score 4):

[The Zimbra communication suite](http://www.zimbra.com/products/zimbra-open-source.html) is apparently pretty popular - I've been investigating it for use at my company, and it pretty much meets all the standard Outlook/Exchange work-alike requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at Proxmox Mail Gateway: http://www.proxmox.com/products/proxmox-mail-gateway

They have a Free [license](http://www.proxmox.com/downloads/mail-gateway/free-license) which appears to restrict to one domain.

Lots of people, including myself, use their free Proxmox VE (Virtualization Environment) product which provides a similar looking GUI web interface. If the quality of that product is any indication, it is probably worth your while to check out the Mail Gateway.

Their [datasheet](http://www.proxmox.com/downloads/mail-gateway/documentation/57-proxmox-mail-gateway-datasheet) includes a table that shows what the Free version does not include.

Cheers